# Cannot scrape for infinite scrolling using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping tweets using Selenium for last 1 years but it cannot scroll the page beyond a point and pointing "Back to Top".
How can I overcome this problem using Selenium?

Here is my code-

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/home/piyush/geckodriver")
url="https://twitter.com/narendramodi"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(6)

lastHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(6)
    newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if newHeight == lastHeight:
         break
    lastHeight = newHeight
```

Here is the output as image
[image: Here is the output as image]

Comment: I don't see any code related to scrapping  ...

Comment: @DebanjanB I haven't attached scraping code, as I want to get rid of this 'back to top' problem. I can scrape the data but the issue is the page is not scrolling after this point.

Comment: This is against the Twitter Terms of Service. Scraping is not allowed.

Comment: @AndyPiper But I can now able to scrape all tweets of an user using twitter advanced search option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following. Try to wait with some timeout until "Back to Top" disappear and then continue to scrape.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    disappeared = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda x: not EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )

    if disappeared:
        print('Continue')
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Where is the attempt to scroll?

Comment: @DebanjanB The question is not about scrolling

Comment: @DebanjanB in short, I want to reach the bottom of the page but it doesn't go to bottom of the page and showing "back to top". How can I disappear this and can load more tweets?

Comment: @A.Albershteyn it throws error as "timeoutexception: message:" .
How to overcome this error?